# closing form after opening other

Tags: forms, delphi

I came across a problem - I have an app in Delphi that launches with form2(set as primary) in unit2 and after some sort of user actions I need the app to open a form1 from unit1 and close the form1, is it possible to have the second form running after closing primary form?

the first form is to get if the user is old enough:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  narozeni,dnes:tdatetime;
  vek:real;
begin
  den:=StrToInt(comboboxden.text);
  if comboboxmesic.text='leden' then mesic:=1
      else if comboboxmesic.text='únor' then mesic:=2
      else if comboboxmesic.text='březen' then mesic:=3
      else if comboboxmesic.text='duben' then mesic:=4
      else if comboboxmesic.text='květen' then mesic:=5
      else if comboboxmesic.text='červen' then mesic:=6
      else if comboboxmesic.text='červenec' then mesic:=7
      else if comboboxmesic.text='srpen' then mesic:=8
      else if comboboxmesic.text='září' then mesic:=9
      else if comboboxmesic.text='říjen' then mesic:=10
      else if comboboxmesic.text='listopad' then mesic:=11
      else if comboboxmesic.text='prosinec' then mesic:=12;
  rok:=StrToInt(comboboxrok.Text);

  narozeni:=encodedate(rok,mesic,den);
  dnes:=date();
  vek:=(dnes-narozeni)/365.25;
  if vek<18 then begin
   showmessage('Pro hraní hazardních her Vám musí být více než 18 let!');
   Application.MainForm.Close;
  end

  else begin
   form1.Show;
  end;

end;
```

then the form1 should open and the 2nd(primary) should be closed. How to do that?

Comment: Closing the Form that is assigned as the `Application.MainForm` will terminate the app.  If you don't want that to happen, hide the Form instead of close it. Or use another Form as the `MainForm`

Comment: Not related to your question but why are you extractng month number by checking ComboBox.Text in a if..else clause? Why not use ComboBox.ItemIndex instead? This way retrieveing month number would be as simple as `mesic := comboboxmesic.ItemIndex+1;` provided you show month names in actual order. Why `+1`?. That is needed because ComboBox item indexes are zero based meaning that first item has index 0.

Comment: As for solution about your question I recommend you search SO about creating of Login forms. While your users are not actually logging in to your system you require the same approach of creating forms as is done with login forms.